# How to rebase feature branch off of master branch often, without force pushing to feature branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitlab

We have a `master` branch, and `feature` branches where we do our work.
My organization follows the rebase workflow.

We branch off the `master` branch:

```
(master)git checkout -b feature
```

After a few commits when it's time to log off for the day, we simply push:

```
(feature)git push
```

Once the feature is ready, we rebase the `feature` branch off of the `master` branch:

```
(feature)git checkout master
(master)git pull
(master)git checkout feature
(feature)git rebase master
```

Solve any merge conflicts in case it's a Monday.
Then we push the local branch to origin, so that the manager can merge it with master using the gitlab interface.
Here, we are forced to force push `feature` to the remote:

```
(feature)git push -f
```

This is pretty much what my entire team does, everyone usually works on different branches so it's not an issue. But I still want to avoid forcing.

Safer alternative:

```
(feature)git push --force-with-lease
```

Using `force-with-lease` fails in case the push was about to override someone else's commits.

But is anyone aware of another way where we avoid any type of force at all.

Possibly something where the rebase shows up as an extra commit?

Comment: As user knittl pointed out, rebasing will recreate all feature branch commits, that means you will need to force-push whenver you rebase. The only alternative I can think of is that instead of rebasing you could merge master into your feature branch (and resolve your monday merge conflicts within that merge) This will preserve the original commits/history and allow your feature branch to be merged into master without conflicts (because you already resolved them within the branch). In that case you would NOT need to force-push.

Comment: I was aware that branches are immutable, so rebase recreates branch commits. But I still haven't understood what exactly you're saying.  
Are you suggesting to:  
1. After rebasing, Merge the master branch into my local feature branch, and push?
2. After rebasing, Pull the remote feature branch into local feature branch, solve MCs and push?

Comment: I'm suggesting to NOT rebase at all, but instead just merge master into feature branch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition, a rebase means you're rewriting the history of your branch - which requires a force-push.

If you want to update your feature branch with the changes from master/main without requiring a force-push afterwards, you need to use a merge (which is *not* a rebase).

Your two options would be a traditional merge-commit, or a squash-and-merge.
Traditional merge commit would just be done like this:

```
git checkout feature
git merge master --no-ff
```

This will both update `feature` with the changes from `master`, and it will make `master` one of the parents of `feature`.

The commit-graph looks like this:

[image: git merge master --no-ff]

The way that you've described it, "something where the rebase shows up as an extra commit?", can be done using a "squash-merge":

```
git checkout feature
git merge --squash master
git commit
```

This will update `feature` with the changes from `master` by squashing all of the changes from master into a single commit onto `feature`. It does not change the parents of `feature`.

This commit-graph looks like this:

[image: git merge --squash]

Answer (score 2):

Rebasing *recreates* your commits as *new* commits. That means that pushes to the same branch will no longer be fast-forward pushes. If you want to push your rebased commits to the same branch, the only way is to use force.

You could push to a new branch (different branch name) to avoid force.